# Declaring my own types and using them in Functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, algebraic-data-types

I am trying to improve my understanding of algebraic data types in Haskell. This example doesn't make much sense, but I am just trying to learn something. The code should be pretty self-explanatory though! Say if I had some code:

```
type Pig = String
type Lion = String
type Feed = [(Char,Char)]
type Visitors = [(Char,Char)]
type Costs = (Int,Int,Int)

data AnimalHome = Farm Pig Pig Pig Feed | Zoo Lion Lion Lion Feed Visitors

orders :: Char -> AnimalHome -> Costs -> Char
orders stuff Farm bert donald horace specialFeed (cost1,cost2,cost3) = some code here
```

Would this be correct so far, or are there some things that I have done wrong?

Comment: You need to put `Farm bert donald horace specialFeed` in parentheses.  You also need to handle the case where the `AnimalHome` is a `Zoo`.

Answer (score 2):

As @GabrielGonzalez has already suggested, you need to put `Farm bert donald horace specialFeed` in parentheses and handle the `Zoo` case:

```
orders :: Char -> AnimalHome -> Costs -> Char
orders stuff (Farm bert donald horace specialFeed) (cost1,cost2,cost3) = undefined
orders stuff (Zoo l1 l2 l3 feed visitors) (c1, c2, c3) = undefined
```

Comment: How would I use the function in the ghci would it work like so:
orders 'C' (Farm abraham charlie edward) (3,7,9)

Comment: @James Did you try it out?  It looks like you might be missing the `Feed` field to `Farm`, but that would be how you call the function.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using more structured types so the typesystem can warn you if you treat visitors as feed (which tends to go down badly in terms of publicity).

### newtype

```
newtype Pig = Pig String
newtype Lion = Lion String
newtype Feed = Feed [(Char,Char)]
```

Here `Pig`s are identically stored, but different in code - `newtype`s get compiled out, but give you type safety so you can't mix them accidentally.

### data vs type

let's try something a little different though:

```
data Visitor = Visitor Char Char -- same data storability as (Char,Char)
type Visitors = [Visitor]
```

It's good to use `type` here to make a synonym - the types `Visitors` and `[Visitor]` are identical, but you can use `Visitors` for slight abbreviation.

### records

Now let's use a record type for Costs:

```
newtype Costs = Costs {capital::Int, consumables::Int, impulse::Int}
```

So I can make a value like `somecosts = Costs {capital=3,consumables=5,impulse=7}` or just `somecosts = Costs 3 5 7` for short, but I get accessor functions for free: `capital somecosts` is `3`, and `consumables somecosts` is `5`.

### repeated fields?

The DBA in me feels worried by

```
data AnimalHome = Farm Pig Pig Pig Feed | Zoo Lion Lion Lion Feed Visitors
```

which I feel should be

```
data AnimalHome = Farm [Pig] Feed | Zoo [Lion] Feed Visitors
```

### using it all

which would make,

```
orders :: Char -> AnimalHome -> Costs -> Char
orders stuff (Farm pigs specialFeed costs) = -- some code here
```

and you could use the accessor functions on the `costs` argument, or nest the pattern matching

```
orders stuff (Farm pigs specialFeed (Costs cap con splurge)) = -- some code here
```